# How to set trigger based on update query in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I am trying to set trigger whenever phone is updated in `table1` and then do operation like check phone from `table2` and if present, pick up the employee code from `table2` and then update employee code in `table1`.

My code for trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER UPDATED_Contact_Trigger 
ON table1 
AFTER UPDATE
AS
    DECLARE @tuid bigint;
    DECLARE @phone varchar(15);
    DECLARE @employee_code varchar(10);

    IF (UPDATE (phone)) --Phone is the Column Name
    BEGIN
        SELECT @employee_code = i.emp_code 
        FROM table2 i (nolock) 
        WHERE i.MOBILE_NO = @phone 

        UPDATE table1 
        SET client_code = @employee_code
        WHERE tuid= @tuid
    END;
```

This trigger is set, but there is no update on `table1` even if I update a contact which is present in `table2`

Comment: Stop littering your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere) until you understand the consequences, anticipate and handle the problems, and have a GOOD reason for using it.

Comment: And notice here how you update based on "@tuid" but never set it. This is one reason why you should provide DDL for the tables involved. No one but you knows your schema and the relationships between tables.

Comment: This code has so many problems it is hard to start. Let's go with the UPDATE function. Many people think this returns true when the value is changed. The reality is that it returns true when that column is in the update statement. It may contain the same value. You don't reference inserted or deleted. You have scalar variables. This is often a sign that the author doesn't understand that triggers fire once per operation, not once per row. And why are you updating another column in the table being updated to have the same value as another column? And NOLOCK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not even looking at the `Inserted` or `Deleted` pseudo tables in your code - how do you want to know what rows have been updated??

`Inserted` is a pseudo table that contains all updated rows - and it contains the **new values** after the update operation, while `Deleted` contains the same rows, but with the **old values** before the update.

You need to do something like this:

- join your `Table1` to `Inserted` to get the rows that were updated (since you didn't show your table structure, I cannot know what your **primary key** on `Table1` is - you need to use that to join to `Inserted`)
- add a join to your `Table2` and pick those rows that have been updated, and limit those to the ones that have been updated in the `Phone` column (by comparing the `Inserted.Phone` value to `Deleted.Phone`)

Try this code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER UPDATED_Contact_Trigger 
ON table1 
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    -- update your base table
    UPDATE t1
    -- set the client_code to the employee_code from Table2
    SET client_code = t2.employee_code
    FROM dbo.Table1 t1
    -- join to "Inserted" to know what rows were updated - use the primary key
    INNER JOIN Inserted i ON t1.(primarykey) = i.(primarykey)
    -- join to "Deleted" to check if the "Phone" has been updated (between Deleted and Inserted)
    INNER JOIN Deleted d ON i.(primarykey) = d.(primarykey)
    -- join to "Table2" to be able to fetch the employee_code
    INNER JOIN dbo.Table2 t2 ON t2.mobile_no = t1.phone
    -- ensure the "Phone" has changed, between the old values (Deleted) and new values (Inserted)
    WHERE i.Phone <> d.Phone;
END;
```

Comment: Hi @marc_s  trigger is working through database but when I update table1 through sql script or calling store procedure in python  , trigger is not working

Comment: @Shubh: what makes you think the trigger doesn't get executed?? A trigger is never dependent on how the update to the table it's assigned to happens - whether it's a SQL GUI tool, a script run from the command line, an `UPDATE` from a programming language - no matter what, the trigger will be fired. You could e.g. make an entry into a "tracking" table as the first line of code in the trigger and verify - I'd be **very surprised** if the trigger was "skipped" when doing certain types of operations....